# How to do OpenQuery in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, t-sql, mongodb-query, openquery

I want to do link mongodb servers within one query like **SQL** Linked server's **OpenQuery** concept. Is it possible in mongoDB?

```
SELECT 
    UserID,
    UserName,
    FirstName,
    LastName
FROM OPENQUERY(remotelinkedservername, 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Users' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do Open query logic in mongoDB but you can connect mongoDB with SQL server by using MongoDB new ODBC Driver with SQL Connector 2.1.0

 

 
A linked server enables you to execute distribute queries against tables stored in a Microsoft SQL Server instance and another data store. Use the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to link your MongoDB data store to a SQL Server instance and then execute distribute queries against both data stores.

Comment: Just would like to add that my company offers a [MongoDB ODBC Driver](https://www.progress.com/odbc/mongodb)

Comment: This company is doing the same thing using Microsoft SQL Server Linked Server with the commercial MongoDB ODBC driver mentioned in the previous comment - https://www.progress.com/customers/killik-co

Comment: ODBC new connector 2.1.0